# Show associated table column as DisplayField in table object in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables `clients` and `users`, `users` belong to `clients`. In `UsersTable.php` I want to set `$ this-> setDisplayField ('Clients.name');` but it does not work. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set display field not by classname, but by name of contained entity:

```
$this->setDisplayField('client.name');
```

Of course in this case, you should contain Clients model in your query.

```
$result = $this->Users->find('list')->contain('Clients');
```

Its possible also in deeper relations.

```
// model
$this->setDisplayField('client.address.street');


//query 
$result = $this->Users->find('list')->contain('Clients.Addresses');
```

*I tested it only in `belongsTo` relation.*